# Axiom of Foundation and transitive sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Assuming the Axiom of Foundation, show that every non-empty transtive set contains $0$ and show that every non-singleton transitive set contains $1$.

It's straightfoward to show the first part.
Suppose that $t$ is a nonempty transitive set.
By the Axiom of Foundation, there is $r \in t$ such that $r \cap t = \emptyset$.
Now, as $r \in t$ and $t$ is transitive, we have that $r \subseteq t$ so that $\emptyset \subseteq r \subseteq r \cap t = \emptyset$, so $\emptyset = r \in t$.

I'm stuck on the second part. If we suppose further that $t$ has at least two elements, then we may consider $q \in t$ with $q \neq \emptyset$.
We can find $p \in q$ with $q \cap p = \emptyset$, but I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Let $t$ be a multipoint transitive set.

As discused $\phi$ in t.

$r = t - \{\phi\}$ is not empty.
By regularity, exists a in r with empty $a \cap r$.
a in $t$;  a subset $t$;  if $x$ in $a$, then $x = \phi$.
As a is not empty, $a = \{\phi\}$, $1$ in $t$ QED.

$\phi$ is empty set.